# How to add existing Java code to Android Studio as a jar/library?

Tags: android, android-studio, jar

I have a jar file called PhoneGestures.jar which contains a bunch of java files I want to use in my project, which I have added to my project as a module using New->Module->Import .Jar :

[image]

I then added this jar module to my project dependencies like so:

[image]

and as you can see it is included in my project's build.gradle:

[image]

But now when I go to use one of the classes from my jar file, like "MobXRotate", for example, Android Studio does not recognise it:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas why this might not be working? Thanks.

Comment: Did you imported the class?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported the class if the class isn't been found either,

try build your project first, that gradle copies the source code in your project structure!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create a new module for a jar file.

Putting the jar file in libs folder will do the trick.

Comment: I got rid of the module and tried copying it into libs, I then made sure it was added to the build.gradle and re-synced the project, but it's still not working. I'm still unable to reference any of the jars classes in my project

Comment: @Highway62 Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding after putting it in libs?